# Whoosh strict exact phrase matches with special characters

Tags: python, whoosh

I'm using **whoosh** to index 100k+ documents because I want to run many literal phrase queries with some special characters such as `"A" Vancouver Island` or `!Action Pact!`.

I've created an index using:

```
schema = Schema(path=ID(stored=True), content=TEXT(analyzer=analysis.StandardAnalyzer(stoplist=None)))
```

And I've tried running searches using a `Phrase`as query, and using `SpanNear2`.

Neither return correct matches. I do not want results similar to `!Action Pact!`, I want a match only if the text contains `!Action Pact!`, word by word, special character by special character, including spaces.